# KeyError: 'model' in attempt_load_one_weight() when building a custom yolov8 model

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, yolo, yolov8

I have built a custom model using YOLOv8 (not training on a custom dataset, but rather customizing the model itself to include a different loss function), but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
File c:\Users\izza\anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\tasks.py:711, in attempt_load_one_weight(weight, device, inplace, fuse)
    709 ckpt, weight = torch_safe_load(weight)  # load ckpt
    710 args = {**DEFAULT_CFG_DICT, **(ckpt.get("train_args", {}))}  # combine model and default args, preferring model args
--> 711 model = (ckpt.get("ema") or ckpt["model"]).to(device).float()  # FP32 model
    713 # Model compatibility updates
    714 model.args = {k: v for k, v in args.items() if k in DEFAULT_CFG_KEYS}  # attach args to model

KeyError: 'model'
```

Here is the code:
**my custom model**

```
# modifying the model to include group sparsity

class GroupSparseClassificationModel(ClassificationModel):
    def __init__(self, cfg, nc, verbose):
        super().__init__(cfg=cfg, nc=nc, verbose=verbose)
    def init_criterion(self):
        return GroupSparseLoss()

class GroupSparseLoss(v8ClassificationLoss):
    def __call__(self, preds, batch):
        loss, loss_items =  super().__call__(preds, batch)
        loss += self.group_lasso_regularization(0.001)
        loss_items += {'group_lasso': loss}
        return loss, loss_items
    

    def group_lasso_regularization(self, lambda_reg_coeff = 0.1): 
        """implements group sparsity using group lasso regularization"""
        x = 0
        print("REGULARIZING...")
        for n, _module in super().model.named_modules(): # TODO: replace with actual model
            if isinstance(_module, nn.Conv2d) and  (not 'downsample' in n):
                p = _module.weight 
                p = p.reshape(p.shape[0],p.shape[1],p.shape[2]*p.shape[3])
                
                #group lasso regularization based on the feature wise grouping
                x += lambda_reg_coeff*torch.sum(torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.sum(p**2,0),1)))

                #group lasso regularization based on the neuron wise grouping
                #x += _lambda*torch.sum(torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.sum(p**2,1),1)))
        return x

class GroupSparseClassificationTrainer(ClassificationTrainer):
    def get_model(self, cfg=None, weights=None, verbose = True):
        model = GroupSparseClassificationModel(cfg, nc=self.data["nc"], verbose=verbose)
        return model
```

**trying to train the model**

```
model = YOLO("yolov8n-cls.pt")
new_model = GroupSparseClassificationModel(cfg='yolov8n-cls.yaml', nc=100, verbose=True)
print(new_model.state_dict())
torch.save(new_model.state_dict(), 'my_model.pt')

args = dict(model='my_model.pt', data=dataset, epochs=1)
trainer = GroupSparseClassificationTrainer(overrides=args)
trainer.train()
```